# jQuery change id element by clicking on anchor link

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change id element on click event of top (anchor link id).
For example:

```
<div id="top-nav-list">
```

Will be chnage to:

```
<div id="new-top-nav-list">
```

Which is inside of this div:  `<div id="top-menu">...</div>`

My jsFiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvGzu/)

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Menu</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
<style type="text/css">
ul{
    list-style:none;
}
#top-menu{
    background:#CCCCCC;
    width:120px;
    padding:2px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}
#left-menu{
    background:#CCCCCC;
    width:120px;
    padding:2px;
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        jQuery('#top').click('mouseover',function(e){
                jQuery('top-nav-list').attr('id','new-nav-list');
        });
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="top">Top</a>  | 
<a href="#" id="left">Left</a>
<br /><br />
<div id="top-menu">
    <div id="top-nav-list">
    <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">One</a></li>
   <li class="two"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
   <li class="three"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="left-menu">
    <div id="top-nav-list">
    <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">One</a></li>
   <li class="two"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
   <li class="three"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this with reference.

```
jQuery('#top').click(function(e){
        jQuery('#top-menu #top-nav-list').attr('id','new-top-nav-list');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
    jQuery('#top').click(function(e){
            jQuery('#top-nav-list').attr('id','new-top-nav-list');
    });
```

`.click()` just has a function argument, there's no event name argument ahead of it (you seemed to be mixing it up with `.on()`). You need to include `#` in the selector for `top-nav-list`. And you left out `-top` in `new-top-nav-list`.

And any design that requires changing the ID of an element seems suspect to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('top-nav-list').attr('id','new-nav-list');
```

(1)You missed to add `#` in your code.  It should look like

```
jQuery('#top-nav-list').attr('id','new-nav-list');
```

(2)Also you can't have like this, 2 event handler like this

```
 jQuery('#top').click('mouseover', function (e) {  // wrong
```

(3)**`ID` should be Unique.**  You can't have same id for multiple elements.  Instead use `class`.

Comment: I think I've figured out that the reason for this JS is that the HTML has duplicate IDs, and he can't fix the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
     jQuery('#top').on("click",function (e) {
        alert(jQuery('#top-nav-list').attr('id'))
    jQuery('#top-nav-list').attr('id', 'new-nav-list');
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/ZvGzu/2/)